# Display AWS S3 images on Ruby app with Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip

I can't seem to get AWS-S3 working with my Ruby app, in both production, and development. I can get the files uploaded to my S3 Bucket, but how do I display them?  I am using this for user profile avatars, so that the users can upload their own avatar.

here is my current image tag:

```
<%= image_tag @user.profile.avatar.url, class: 'user-show-avatar' %>
```

I've place my avatar upload info in the profiles model which is where I have the avatar information.

profile.rb

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_attached_file  :avatar, 
                    :styles => { :medium => "460x>", :thumb => "100x100>",:vnice=> "400x" },
                    :storage => :s3,
                    :bucket => 'mybucket',
                    :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/aws.yml",
                    :path => "resources/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"

    validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

end
```

_form.html.erb (edit profile form)

```
<%= form_for @profile, url: user_profile_path, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :avatar %>
          <%= f.file_field :avatar, class: 'form-control' %>
        </div>
<% end %>
```

config/initializer/paperclip.rb

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:storage] = :s3

Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_credentials] = {
  :bucket => ENV['AWS_BUCKET'],
  :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_KEY'],
  :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_KEY'],
  s3_region: 'us-east-1'
}

Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_options] = {
  endpoint: 'https://objects-us-east-1.io'
}

Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] = ':s3_domain_url'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = '/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_host_name] = 'objects-us-east-1'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_protocol] = 'https'
```

What am I doing wrong? What is the proper way to display images in Ruby, from S3 using paperclip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

Deleted the paperclip.rb initialiser, and added :url => ':s3_domain_url' to my profile model